# Magento 1.9.x: Pricing rule is not working for sub products of a configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, price-rules

I have a configurable product and associated sub products. When I am applying rule for all it is working properly but if I apply rule only for specific category (which is assigned to sub product of that configurable product) the pricing rule is not working in front-end. I am clicking on "Apply Rule" button after creating rule, cleaning cache and re-indexing but not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically magento dont provide this feature, you may need an extension :

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

same extension  in magento connect  : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

I am posting sample of extension code here :

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php';

class OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_AjaxController extends Mage_Catalog_ProductController
{
    public function coAction()
    {
       $product = $this->_initProduct();
       if (!empty($product)) {
           $this->loadLayout(false);
           $this->renderLayout();
       }
    }

    public function imageAction()
    {
       $product = $this->_initProduct();
       if (!empty($product)) {
           $this->loadLayout(false);
           $this->renderLayout();
       }
    }

    public function galleryAction()
    {
       $product = $this->_initProduct();
       if (!empty($product)) {
           #$this->_initProductLayout($product);
           $this->loadLayout();
           $this->renderLayout();
       }
    }

    //Copy of parent _initProduct but changes visibility checks.
    //Reproducing functionality like this is far from great for future compatibilty
    //but at the moment I don't see a better alternative.
    protected function _initProduct()
    {
        $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
        $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $parentId   = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('pid');

        if (!$productId || !$parentId) {
            return false;
        }

        $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($parentId);

        if (!Mage::helper('catalog/product')->canShow($parent)) {
            return false;
        }

        $childIds = $parent->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();
        if (!is_array($childIds) || !in_array($productId, $childIds)) {
            return false;
        }

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);
        // @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
        if (!$product->getId()) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($categoryId) {
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
            Mage::register('current_category', $category);
        }
        $product->setCpid($parentId);
        Mage::register('current_product', $product);
        Mage::register('product', $product);
        return $product;
    }
}
```

**Update**  :

**Note** : please take backup of files and database for safety purpose before installing any extension or try the extension in demo/staging site.

you can download extension folders and files from here  : https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple , than you need to copy that extension folders to root of the site... and do the configuration as present in extension link  : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

Comment: Where to write this code (Please explain with folder structure)? Sorry I am new in Magento. https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html this in upto 1.5 only.

Comment: @PankajVerma please check `update` part in answer..... also i tried this extension in 1.8 , it worked for me, i hope it will work in 1.9. also you may wait for some more time, so that you may get better answer than this.....

Comment: But the extension is Compatible with: 1.4, 1.4.1.1, 1.4.2, 1.5 only. I am using 1.9.3

Comment: @PankajVerma in github link, you can see they mentioned it is compatible with 1.7 : http://prntscr.com/fx6opz ....  as i said , it worked for me in 1.8.... you can keep this extension as last option , hopefully you will get better answer....